# adding a filename to a list in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i have a method that opens a file and then calls another method,
which opens up a window (i am using tkinter) that asks the user whether he would like to open another file. Now, each time  a file gets opened i want to add the filename to a list, but in my case when i look at the result the list only contains the last selected filename. 
I will include my stripped down code:

```
def fileopening(self):
    from tkinter.dialog import askopenfilename
    import os.path
    self.inputfilenamelist = []
    self.fileopenname.set(askopenfilename(filetypes = [("binary files","*.bin*"),("all files","*.*")]))
    basename = os.path.basename(self.fileopenname.get())
    self.inputfilenamelist.append(basename)
    self.askforanotherinput()

def askforanotherinput(self):
    inputwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    inputwindow.title("Inputselection")
    inputwindow.minsize(400,200)
    asklabel = tk.Label(inputwindow,text="Select another inputfile?")
    asklabel.pack()
    answeryesbutton = tk.Button(inputwindow,text="Yes")
    answeryesbutton.pack()
    answeryesbutton["command"]=lambda:[inputwindow.destroy(),self.fileopening()]
    answernobutton = tk.Button(inputwindow,text="No")
    answernobutton.pack()
    answernobutton["command"]=lambda:[inputwindow.destroy(),self.fileopeningcounter.set(0)]
```

Can anyone help me ? The thing is i need this "method-calling-loop" since i am using the opened files in further data conversion as a whole.

Comment: You are reinitializing `self.inputfilenamelist` each time you run `self.fileopening()`. You should put  `self.inputfilenamelist = []` inside `__init__` instead.

Comment: ok thanks, that makes sense, it worked now!